# Add points after every 2 characters entered on textfields extjs 5

Tags: javascript, extjs, textfield

how can i add points (.) after every 2 characters on text field.

Is there any specific way to do that?

My Code:

```
var txtNoNpwp = {
  afterLabelTextTpl: required,
  allowBlank: false,
  anchor: '100%',
  labelAlign: 'left',
  labelWidth: 130,
  fieldLabel: 'No NPWP',
  id: 'txtNoNpwp',
  name: 'txtNoNpwp',
  xtype: 'textfield'
};
```

Comment: You can capture keyup event and add `.` after every second  character. I guess this is as far I can do without seeing your code. Please share your code and **where you are stuck**

Comment: This might help: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?106101-Keyup-on-a-TextField-SearchFIeld

Comment: thanks @Rajesh i will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the value to the desired format in the `change` event.
Whenever the value of the field changes it is called with the new and the old value.

First remove the previous format with the following code.

```
newValue = newValue.replace(/\./g, '');
```

Then apply the new format.

```
newValue = newValue.replace(/.{2}/g, function (substr) {
    return substr + '.'
});
```

Finally you have to set the new value with

```
field.setRawValue(newValue);
```

The full code should be something like this, see the [working Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1tps).

```
var txtNoNpwp = {
    listeners: {
        change: function (field, newValue) {
            newValue = newValue.replace(/\./g, ''); // remove previous format
            newValue = newValue.replace(/.{2}/g, function (substr) { // apply new format
                return substr + '.'
            });
            field.setRawValue(newValue);
        }
    },
    xtype: 'textfield',
    //...
};
```

Comment: This answer worked best for me. big thanks ! @Andy-y